# Deep clone document with embedded associations

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

How would you go about deep cloning a document in MongoDB (mongoid)

I've tried something like this;

```
original = Car.find(old_id)
@car = original.clone
@car._id = BSON::ObjectId.new
```

But I get problems deserialization of the values afterwards.

How can I make a deep clone with all the documents attributes except the _id?

Edit:
After following Zachary's example I got some problems with a custom serialization class for the duplicated documents.

```
class OptionHash
  include Mongoid::Fields::Serializable

  # Convert the keys from Strings to Symbols
  def deserialize(object)
    object.symbolize_keys!
  end

  # Convert values into Booleans
  def serialize(object)
    object.each do |key, value|
    object[key] = Boolean::MAPPINGS[value]
  end
end
```

Object is nil for duplicated documents.
Car.find(old_id).attributes indeed doesn't include the field with the custom serialization, why is that and how can I include it?

Comment: can you be more specific about the problems?

Comment: What problems do you have later?

Comment: I guess the problem is that the embedded document's ids doesn't get updated. i.e conflicting with the ids of the embedded documents in the original document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to call .clone on this, you can use the raw data from `attributes`. For example the below method/example will give new ids throughout the entire document if it finds one.

```
def reset_ids(attributes)
    attributes.each do |key, value|
        if key == "_id" and value.is_a?(BSON::ObjectId)
            attributes[key] = BSON::ObjectId.new
        elsif value.is_a?(Hash) or value.is_a?(Array)
            attributes[key] = reset_ids(value)
        end        
    end
    attributes
end


original = Car.find(old_id)
car_copy = Car.new(reset_ids(original.attributes))
```

And you now have a copy of Car. This is inefficient though as it has to go through the entire hash for the record to figure out if there are any embedded documents in an embedded document. You would be better off resetting the structure yourself if you know how it'll be, for example, if you have a parts embedded into car, then you can just do:

```
original = Car.find(old_id)
car_copy = Car.new(original.attributes)
car_copy._id = BSON::ObjectId.new
car_copy.parts.each {|p| p._id = BSON::ObjectId.new}
```

Which is a lot more efficient than just doing a generic reset.

Comment: Hi thanks, updated the question since I got some problems with this approach.

Comment: Hrm. I don't have much experience with Mongoid::Fields::Serializable. I would check to see what type of data is being passed when you call `original.attributes`. Are you getting the serialized data or the deserialized data? It's possibly an issue with it passing the deserialized data so you need to serialize it before cloning.

Comment: Excellent post.. I only had to account for the mass_assignment security in rails3 to make this work. 
By removing the attr_accessible from the model it worked like a charm.. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting error `NameError: uninitialized constant BSON`. The `_id` holds `String` value.

Comment: Since Mongoid switched to Moped, you have to use: `Moped::BSON::ObjectId`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Car.instantiate` if you have localized fields so the code is

```
def reset_ids(attributes)
    attributes.each do |key, value|
        if key == "_id" && value.is_a?(Moped::BSON::ObjectId)
            attributes[key] = Moped::BSON::ObjectId.new
        elsif value.is_a?(Hash) || value.is_a?(Array)
            attributes[key] = reset_ids(value)
        end        
    end
    attributes
end

car_original = Car.find(id)
car_copy = Car.instantiate(reset_ids(car_original.attributes))
car_copy.insert
```

This solution is not very clean but i don't have found better.