# How do you create a copy / dup a mongoid object?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

ActiveRecord safely [supports dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record), but mongoid doesn't appear to handle it properly.

I'd like to do the following:

```
x = MyModel.new
x.save
y = x.dup
y.save
```

And y should be a totally new object such that:

```
x != y
x.id != y.id
```

Comment: Looks like someone already got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793647/deep-clone-document-with-embedded-associations

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
x = Item.new
x.save
y = x.clone
y.save
```

It should change the _id and copy all the other fields. I've noticed this doesn't seem to work with embedded documents though. For each embedded doc in the original, it creates a blank embedded doc in the clone with a new id, but doesn't populate any of the other fields.

If working with embedded docs it might be better to write your own class method.