# Cloning documents within a Mongo database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongodb database that I use mongoid to access via a rails 3 application. The database consists of around 10-15 collections. Some of the documents in these collections have embedded documents and other documents are linked by id.

I need to clone most of the data in the database to create new records. These new records will need to co-exist with their cloned counterparts while they are translated by our client. These new records must maintain the same relationships as they did before however the newly cloned records need to point to their newly cloned counterparts.

Considerations include: A number of has one relationships that have a "foreign key" that will need to be updated on clone. Some documents have embedded documents that will need to be cloned with their parents.  Clonee documents will not be able to relate to their cloned documents in anyway.

Solutions Considered: The first option was to duplicate the database and try and merge everything that does not need to be cloned. Might be a little messy and I am assuming that existing ID would get cloned too. The second option I considered was to write a script that would iterate though each Mongoid document class and called clone however I found out that monogid.clone does a shallow copy not a deep drudge. So for this solution I would have to write a case in which embedded relationships where detected in order to perform a deep copy. This also could get messy.

Is there an option I have not considered here?  Is there a better way to go about one of the considered solutions? Am I up against it?

Comment: I think you're stuck with the messy version, that's pretty much what I've done whenever I've needed to copy stuff in MongoDB.

Comment: Hey @muistooshort do you mean use .clone?

Comment: If `clone` isn't handling the embedded docs then get messier and do it all by hand. I tend to do it all by hand but I'm not using Mongoid.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for clearing that up. I will have a look in to doing it by hand.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing like SQL's `insert ... select ...` in MongoDB. At least nothing that I know of.

Comment: Well you could use mongoid to handle all  the "insert" and "select" statements. I guess it's getting these clones to work as needed. One place to start with this might be here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793647/deep-clone-document-with-embedded-associations

Answer (score 0):

Watching the discussion in the comments, I'd say that if .clone does not work, you can easily do that in a compact way with the attributes, read_attribute, write_attribute methods. [Excerpt from here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html).

```
# Get the field values as a hash.
person.attributes

# Set the field values in the document.
Person.new(first_name: "Jean-Baptiste", middle_name: "Emmanuel")
person.attributes = { first_name: "Jean-Baptiste", middle_name: "Emmanuel" }
person.write_attributes(
  first_name: "Jean-Baptiste",
  middle_name: "Emmanuel"
)
```