# NoMethodError (undefined method `assign_attributes' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clone, nested-attributes

I want to implement a clone feature, where a user can clone existing records into a new record.
The model i want to clone is OpdRecord, also i have model Medication nested inside the OpdRecord form, so both are created after submitting the form.
When i clone using the following code

```
opd_record = OpdRecord.find_by(:id => params[:opd_record_id]) 
@opdrecord=opd_record.dup
```

the nested attribites are no getting cloned.
and when i save

```
@opdrecord = OpdRecord.new(record_params)
@opdrecord.save
```

reord params below

```
def record_params
    params.require(:opdrecord).permit!
  end
```

i get the following error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `assign_attributes' for nil:NilClass):
```

How can i manage to save the nested attributes as well

Answer (score 0):

Use [deep_cloneable](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable) gem OR [amoeba](https://rubygems.org/gems/amoeba) gem

With Deep_Cloneable Do it like :

```
opd_record = OpdRecord.find_by(:id => params[:opd_record_id]) 
@opd_record = opd_record.deep_clone :include => [:medication ] # change it as per your model relations
```

Comment: does this support mongoid embededd attributes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793647/deep-clone-document-with-embedded-associations